# How to hide the particular tab header of goldenLayout

Tags: javascript, jquery, polymer, golden-layout

```
myLayout.config.settings.hasHeaders = false;
```

I am using this one, but this is hiding all tab headers. I need to hide particular tab header only? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Since I have been playing with this for over a month now and am very committed at this point, I thought I would start to contribute to the `golden-layout` community tag.

https://github.com/deepstreamIO/golden-layout/blob/master/src/js/LayoutManager.js#L816

```
if( config.settings.hasHeaders === false ) {
            config.dimensions.headerHeight = 0;
        }
```

If you look at the line of code I reference above, this is how GL uses the setting. So what you could do is just set the `headerheight` of the specific item.

Also since this only touches the `headerheight` if thats equal to false, you can have it at true and pick and chose which ones you want to show headers for.

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use css, like this but you must check if it works fine for you (example in Sass):

```
.layout-no-header {
  > .lm_item {
    height: 100% !important;
    > .lm_header {
      height: 0 !important;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    > .lm_items {
      height: 100% !important;
      > .lm_item_container {
        height: 100% !important;
        > .lm_content {
          height: 100% !important;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

also to add css to an item in golden-layout, add something like this:

```
this.layout.on('itemCreated', function (item) {
  if (item.config.cssClass) {
    const classes = _.isArray(item.config.cssClass) ? item.config.cssClass : item.config.cssClass.split(' ');
    classes.forEach(c => {
      item.element.addClass(c);
    });
  }
});
```

and in your layout configuration, add

```
cssClass: 'layout-no-header'
```